# Some fields in Google sheet are not recognized by GDS

Tags: google-sheets, looker-studio

I have a simple Google sheet that has **9 fields** as shown below
[Google sheet data source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UX9q8.png)
When I connect this file as a data source using Google Sheets connector, I get ONLY **7 fields** instead of 9 as shown below:

[Data Source Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9gCC.png)

There are two missing files that cannot be recognized by GDS which are scenario and feedback fields respectively.

In order to solve this issue, I tried the following:
disconnect and reconnect the data source file again. But it did not work.
Also, I tried to use refresh fields but in vain too.
I tried also.
I could not find any reason for that behavior. please help if you can.

Here is a link to a sample Google Sheet file.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GIHjwPp0uodUiJeXeX9RVr58hFz2re-6ilZYAeFU_Lc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are these missing columns in your original google sheets file also empty? If yes, this is the reason why GDS is not recognizing those table. If you add some value in at least one row of these columns and reconnect the data source, they will show up.

If you intend to keep those columns empty for whatever reason, you can make a row with 'test' as values and filter those out in the report after connecting the data source.